# AdminLTE with pixel differences

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, adminlte

I'm trying to implement a site using AdminLTE template. After setting up the skeleton page i get a small pixel rendering issue with font-awesome icons. In my site the icons are slightly raised as you can see in the attached screenshots:

[image: standard AdminLTE]
[image: my site]

As you can see the icons are at a slightly higher position than the normal one. The user menu stays at the same position.

I've looked at the CSS properties using Chrome dev tools but can't see any difference.

Anyone has a clue of what it can be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post some fiddle.so that we can look over your code.

Comment: The code is basically copy-paste from de starter page of AdminLTE. The only difference is i bundle all css into one unique file using Laravel Mix (based on webpack).